# How to send 0x99 with java?

Tags: java, byte

Because java has no unsigned byte. 0x99 will be negative numbers.
how to send 0x99 with java?

The server side is written by c.

How to send the correct byte?

Comment: depends on how you send it, but sending negative byte `0x99` should be fine in most cases and if someone who reads it will interpret is as unsigned, he will see `0x99` and not the negative value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0x99 is 99 in hex, which in decimal can be represented as a negative number, but is still 0x99 in hex and have the same binary representation.

So, sending it on a socket, wether you write it as 0x99 (hex), C unsigned byte 153 (decimal) or java signed byte -103 (decimal), it will still send the bits 10011001.

If you instead are sending it in decimal, that is you are not sending a single byte as binary on the socket, but the ascii representation of it like '-','1','0','3', then it's easier if in java you use int, int i = 0x99 will be 153 decimal, so converted to a string will be '1','5','3' and not a negative decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

Just send 0x99 as hex value. The opposite site is responsible for its correct interpretation. 0x99h is always 0x99h which is always the same byte sequence! Real Byte representation has nothing to do if its negative or not. This depends on the interpretation